# wordpress posts images zoom on mouseover

Tags: php, wordpress, zooming

please suggest a free way to add zoom effect on my wordpress posts images, i am trying magic zoom for whole day but it's not working, plugin installed activated but it's not showing my posts images like that it claims, no scipt file appearing in header, and also how to change image class, default class for posts images is "alignnone". Please help

Comment: Maybe the fine folks over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com would be better able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this free plugin: http://www.dynamicwp.net/plugins/image-zoomer-plugin/

Comment: integration is a issue with this plugin, it's activated but again not magnifying my post images